# How to append '=' to a string

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to add `=` at the end of my array and then end it by appending a 0

This is how I allocate my space

```
char* postExpr = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LEN);
```

I have tried many methods but I am still failing to append character '=' at the end of my string, every other character works just fine.

What have I tried

```
postExpr[postLen++] = 61;
postExpr[postLen++] = '=';
postExpr[postLen++] = infExpr[i];
```

in infExpr[i] is stored the value '='

EDIT:

```
char* infix2postfix (const char* infExpr) {
    char* postExpr = malloc (sizeof(char)*MAX_LEN);
    if(postExpr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    tStack* s = (tStack*) malloc(sizeof(tStack));
    if(s == NULL)
    {
        free(postExpr);
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned postLen = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< MAX_LEN; i++)
    {
        switch(infExpr[i])
        {
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '+':
            case '-': doOperation(s,infExpr[i],postExpr,&postLen); break;

            case '(': stackPush(s,infExpr[i]); break;
            case ')': untilLeftPar(s,postExpr,&postLen); break;
            case '=': 
            while(!stackEmpty(s))
            {
                stackTop(s,&postExpr[postLen++]);
                stackPop(s);
            }
            postExpr[postLen++] = '='; //NO APPEND HERE!!!
            postExpr[postLen++] = 0;
            postLen = MAX_LEN;
            break;
            case 0:
            postExpr[postLen++] = '=';
            postExpr[postLen++] = 0;
            postLen = MAX_LEN;
            break;
            default: postExpr[postLen++] = infExpr[i];  break;
        }
    }
    return postExpr;
}
```

Comment: Show the full code, please. There is nothing special about this character.

Comment: What's posted here isn't enough to show the problem.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see the posted snipped in the code itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well you could tell me how can I make my code more beautiful. I have to fill only this function and I don't see any other way of writing it better.

Comment: For example get rid of these `goto`s there. They are not doing anything anyway.

Comment: They are breaking the for cycle. Is there any other way to break for from switch ?

Comment: Set a flag and check it in the `for` condition. Or with another `if` which will `break`. But this is not your question, right? So where is that code snippet you have shown in the beginning?

Comment: @EugeneSh. well I edited it and added comment where am I appending it in '=' case

Comment: @EugeneSh. - come on, now. `goto`'s make some of us wax nostalgic about our salad days as spaghetti coders. Ah, great days - GREAT days... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis I must admit I have missed these days... the only `goto` I have written were in Basic back in school..

Comment: how do you know it's not getting appended, are you trying to print the string somewhere? My guess is you already have a `NUL` terminator somewhere in the string, `postLen` is advancing beyond that in a manner you don't expect (probably due to the `while` loop before where you're trying to append), and so you're not seeing `=` when you add it. Put a break point right there and check the value of `postLen`. Also print out the memory of `postExpr` right after you append the `=`.

Comment: At a minimum, I'd recommend some `printf()`'s before the `switch` statement and before the append of `'='`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my stack, I forgot to initializate it, so it would store value 0 which was appended before '=' and thus made the char unreadable

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are adding `=` probably after `0` which is previously present there.So,

```
        postExpr[postLen++] = '=';
        postExpr[postLen++] = 0;
```

should be

```
        postExpr[postLen-1] = '=';
        postExpr[postLen++] = 0;
```

Or there would be `NULL` terminator in your string before.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found out my solution, I added answer if you are interested in knowing more. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're passing the address of `postLen` to a lot of different subroutines.

And then you're complaining that a simple assignment of a character in an array, *indexed by the variable you were passing around* is not working.

My advice would be to do two things:

1. First, in the `case '=':` part of your code, print out the `postLen` and also the `strlen(postExpr)` to check if they are in sync.
2. Second, start looking into your various subroutines to see if you can determine where the `postLen` value is going wrong.