# How to append to a given string in a Tstringlist

Tags: delphi, append, tstringlist

I'm creating lists of email addresses implemented as csv strings in a TStringlist by appending each new email to an existing csv string. If the csv string in MyStringlist[0] already contains the email I'm about to add then I'll append it to MyStringlist[1]. If that string also already contains it then I'll append it to MyStringlist[2] and so on until I find a string that doesn't contain it.

The problem occurs if, for example, MyStringlist[0] and MyStringlist[1] both contain the email I want to append but MyStringlist[2] doesn't yet exist so it can't be appended to.

e.g. I might need to add 'a.co.uk' to MyStringlist that already contains the strings below.

```
MyStringlist[0] -> a.co.uk, f.co.uk, h.co.uk, k.co.uk
MyStringlist[1] -> d.co.uk, a.co.uk, g.co.uk
```

I created a procedure to append an email to a string at a given index or create a new string in the stringlist if necessary.

Is this code the correct way to do it or are there functions I should use to do this in a simpler way - or maybe in a more robust way?

Procedure created

```
procedure AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList: Tstringlist;
                                 Index : integer;
                                 StringToAppend : string);
var i : integer;
begin
if Index >= 0 then
  begin
  if TheStringList.count -1 < index then //not enough strings
    begin
    for i := 1 to index - TheStringList.Count  do  //add a blank string
       TheStringList.add('');
    TheStringList.add( StringToAppend); //add new string at position 'index'
    end
  else //just append
     TheStringList[Index] :=  TheStringList[Index] + ',' + StringToAppend
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Ken White. The tag 'Delphi' in the title is not redundant. Most people use Google to search for answers and certainly I get quite fed up getting hits on SO questions only to find they're for the wrong language. Sure, if I just use SO's search then I can limit results by using tags, but (a) it means I've got to choose to look in SO in the first place, (b) I've got to know enough about SO to search by tags and (c) I have to hope the OP uses the right tag. Putting Delphi in the title immediately shows what language is being used to both SO and Google users. Nothing is gained by removing it.

Comment: The tag information IS redundant. If you search Google for *Delphi* and the title of this question (wihtout the tag infrormation), it is found in the search results because the tags are picked up by Google's logic.  The tagging system here is very effocient, and doesn't need help by redundant noise in the title. I've removed it again. Please do NOT edit it back in, because it is inappropriate. Thank you.

Comment: A search for how to append to a string bring me to, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715642/how-to-append-to-a-string. Great I think. That is until I waste my time going there only to find the question is using the C language and not Delphi. If C had been in the title I wouldn't have looked at that post. I don't consider that 'redundant noise' I think it is useful, even essential,  information to have in the title, given that SO is supposed to be generating an archive of useful questions and answers.

Comment: If you search using `[delphi` at the beginning of your search expression (that's the Delphi **tag**), you don't get posts related to C. I don't know why you continue with this nonsense. Tag information goes in the **tags**, not the title. The tag system works **extremely well** here and doesn't need clutter in the title to help it.

Comment: I'll stop this 'nonsense' now as you seem more interested in criticising  my simple question than answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function to ensure a `TStrings`/`TStringList` has a minimum number of strings. So yes, you will have to add strings manually one at a time.

I would suggest something more like this:

```pascal
procedure AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList: TStrings;
                                 Index : integer;
                                 StringToAppend : string);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if Index < 0 then Exit;
  TheStringList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    while Index >= TheStringList.Count do begin
      TheStringList.Append('');
    end;
    s := TheStringList[Index];
    if s = '' then 
      s := StringToAppend
    else
      s := s + ',' + StringToAppend;
    TheStringList[Index] := s;
  finally
    TheStringList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

However, this does require you to know the desired index ahead of time, which means searching the `TStringList` beforehand, eg:

```pascal
function AlreadyExistsInStringListItem(const S, StringToAppend: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;

function FindIndexToAppendToStringListItem(TheStringList: TStrings;
                                           StringToAppend : string);
begin
  for Result := 0 to TheStringList.Count-1 do
  begin
    if not AlreadyExistsInStringListItem(TheStringList[Result], StringToAppend) then
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := TheStringList.Count;
end;

procedure AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList: TStrings;
                                 Index : integer;
                                 StringToAppend : string);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if Index < 0 then Exit;
  TheStringList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    while Index >= TheStringList.Count do begin
      TheStringList.Append('');
    end;
    s := TheStringList[Index];
    if s = '' then 
      s := StringToAppend
    else
      s := s + ',' + StringToAppend;
    TheStringList[Index] := s;
  finally
    TheStringList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
Index := FindIndexToAppendToStringListItem(TheStringList, 'a.co.uk');
AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList, Index, 'a.co.uk');
```

Depending on your code's design, that could be wasted overhead.  You could simplify that logic by merging the searching and inserting together, eg:

```pascal
function AlreadyExistsInStringListItem(const S, StringToAppend: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;

procedure AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList: TStrings;
                                 StringToAppend : string);
var
  i : integer;
  s: string;
begin
  TheStringList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to TheStringList.Count-1 do
    begin
      s := TheStringList[i];
      if not AlreadyExistsInStringListItem(s, StringToAppend) then
      begin
        TheStringList[i] := s + ',' + StringToAppend;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    TheStringList.Append(StringToAppend);
  finally
    TheStringList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
AppendToStringListItem(TheStringList, 'a.co.uk');
```

Comment: I know I am nitpicking here, but the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate is meaningless as there is only one operation that actually changes TheStringList: Either the assignment or the Append.

Comment: Knowing the index ahead of time is OK as I'm reading from a dataset ordered by email so within the while not eof loop reading the dataset there is logic that increments a batch number every time I get a duplicate email and uses that batch number as the stringlist index I want. It then resets the batch number back to 0 on reaching the end of the duplicates so the next email goes in index 0

Comment: @UweRaabe Sure, for a `TStringList`. But if you notice, I changed the input parameter from `TStringList` to `TStrings`, which opens up the code to work with all kinds of descendants, for example `TMemo.Lines`, where it makes more sense to use `(Begin|End)Update()` especially when making multiple updates at a time, like multiple calls to `Append()`.

Comment: Thank you Remy. At least I know I'm not missing something simple. In this case its important I pass which index I want to use as I need to also append a CSV string of JSON data to a similar stringlist at the same index. This creates batches of emails and corresponding JSON mailmerge header data at the same index to send to a bulk emailer API, knowing that each batch contains no duplicate emails. (So If two people share an email address I can send different mailmerge data to each of them by using a different batch). Answer accepted